# Playing video using swift 2 IOS 9

Tags: video, swift2, ios9

I'm looking for an example Or source code for playing videos from my application using AVKIT. I couldn't find example of using new version of Swift 2 (IOS 9). Since the MPmovieplayercontroller is deprecated in IOS 9. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the guide [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), especially the part on Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE). This will help you solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and what the results were so we can better help you.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`AVPlayerViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayerViewController) class available in iOS 8.0 and later:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
         super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let moviePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample_iPod", ofType: "m4v")
        if let path = moviePath {
            let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
            let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
            let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
            playerViewController.player = player
            self.presentViewController(playerViewController, animated: true) {
                if let validPlayer = playerViewController.player {
                    validPlayer.play()
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

EDITED:

That's how you can play the movie without additional screen and custom size:

```
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path)
    let player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player

    playerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(20, 50, 300, 300)
    self.view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
    self.addChildViewController(playerViewController)

    player.play()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.  How do I customize the video to play on existing screen with particular size instead of opening a new Avplayer screen.  Also the video was placed inside asset folder and made reference in the bundle , but it was unable to find the video, I've to manually add reference  to the video in the bundle instead of just referring to asset folder.

Comment: Edited my answer with update for ```playerViewController``` screen appearance and movie frame size. And need to clarify how you are adding the movie to answer the second part of your comment